# R function to loop over variable names using mutate and ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataframe with multiple variables where I've divided the variables into three categories. The first is a list of variables which I'll call the case 1 variables. The second is the variables that I'll call the case 2 variables. The length of the first and second lists are the same (call that length k) and the ith element of the case 1 list has the same class as the ith element of the case 2 list. The third is a single-element list which is the "which" variable that tells me what case should apply.

I'd like to do is loop from i = 1 to k and create k new variables, where the ith variable becomes the ith element of the first list if which = 1 and becomes the ith element of the second list if which = 2. If which = NA (or any other value), then the ith variable of the new list is NA. I'd like this to be robust to whether the ith element is string, numeric, or logical. And of course, I'd like to do this without manually typing out the variable lists into the code.

I've come up with one solution using get(). However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this and/or whether there are potential pitfalls by using get().

```
rm(list = ls())

library(dplyr)

case <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1)
v1A <- c(45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105, 115, 125, 135)
v2A <- c(-45, -55, -65, -75, -85, -95, -105, -115, -125, -135)
v1B <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
v2B <- c("z","y","x","w","v","u","t","s","r","q")
df <- data.frame(which_case = case, var1A = v1A, var2A = v2A, var1B = v1B, var2B = v2B)

newvar <- c("varA","varB")
var1 <- c("var1A","var1B")
var2 <- c("var2A","var2B")

# test whether TRUE (and returns FALSE if FALSE OR NA):
is_true <- function(x) { return(x==TRUE & !is.na(x)) }
# test whether FALSE (and return FALSE if TRUE OR NA):
is_false <-function(x) { return(x==FALSE & !is.na(x)) }


for (i in 1:length(newvar)) {
  newvar_i = newvar[i]
  var1_i = var1[i]
  var2_i = var2[i]
  df <- df %>% mutate({{newvar_i}} := NA)
  df <- df %>% mutate({{newvar_i}} := ifelse(is_true(which_case==1), get(var1_i), get(newvar_i)))
  df <- df %>% mutate({{newvar_i}} := ifelse(is_true(which_case==2), get(var2_i), get(newvar_i)))
  #df <- df %>% mutate(!!newvar_i := get(var1_i))
}

print(df)

   which_case var1A var2A var1B var2B varA varB
1           1    45   -45     a     z   45    a
2           2    55   -55     b     y  -55    y
3           2    65   -65     c     x  -65    x
4           1    75   -75     d     w   75    d
5           2    85   -85     e     v  -85    v
6           1    95   -95     f     u   95    f
7           1   105  -105     g     t  105    g
8          NA   115  -115     h     s   NA <NA>
9           2   125  -125     i     r -125    r
10          1   135  -135     j     q  135    j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_orig <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  which_case = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1),
  var1A = c(45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105, 115, 125, 135),
  var2A = c(-45, -55, -65, -75, -85, -95, -105, -115, -125, -135),
  var1B = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),
  var2B = c("z", "y", "x", "w", "v", "u", "t", "s", "r", "q")
)

newvar <- c("varA", "varB")
var1 <- c("var1A", "var1B")
var2 <- c("var2A", "var2B")

library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)

c_build <- function(v1, v2) {
  force(v1)
  force(v2)
  \(x){
    vv1 <- eval(ensym(v1), envir = caller_env())
    vv2 <- eval(ensym(v2), envir = caller_env())
    case_match(
      x,
      1 ~ vv1,
      2 ~ vv2
    )
  }
}
mbuild <- function(n) {
  imap(
    n,
    \(n, y){
      c_build(
        var1[[y]],
        var2[[y]]
      )
    }
  ) |> set_names(n)
}
myfuncs <- mbuild(newvar)

df2 <- df_orig |> mutate(across(which_case, 
                                myfuncs, 
                                .names = "{.fn}"))
```